# Laravel - Sort Eloquent Query Results by Column Non-Numeric Order [2, 1, 3, etc]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The idea is to paginate the result and sort them by column 'status' in a specific order: [2, 1, ...], so the pending articles (2) are shown first, then active (1), etc etc.

Assuming this next code is the starting point:

```
$articles = Article::paginate(8);
```

Does anyone has an idea on such method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you looking for orderBy ? or i'm wrong ? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: @Skyro682 it's kind of that, but the difference is that I want it to be in non numeric order, like [2, 1, 3], and that other method will order it in numeric order [1, 2, 3, etc]. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: One way is to set the column status as a foreign key for a status table where you put the name of the status and the orders you want. Then you orderby the order columns from status table. i didn't see anything else

Comment: I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user **orderByRaw** function and `FIELD` in mysql

```
Article::query()->orderByRaw('FIELD(status, 2,1,10,3) DESC');
```

Comment: You're a legend!